# Crying when reading about Aaron's sons' deaths

Tags: death, children-parenting, parashat-shemini, parshat-acharei-mot

The *machzor* (prayer book) that I used this Yom Kippur has this to say immediately before the morning Torah reading:

> עֶס שְׁטֵייט גֶעשְׁרִיבֶּן װֶער עֶס לָאזט טְרֶערִין מִיט דֶעם גַאנְצֶן הַארְץ בְּשַׁעַת מֶען לֵייעֶנְט װִי דִי צְװֵיי זִיהְן פוּן אַהֲרֹן הַכֹּהֵן זֶענֶן גִשְׁטָארְבֶּן. אִיז עֶר בָּטוּחַ אַז זַיינֶע קִינְדֶר װֶעלֶן נִיט שְׁטַארְבֶּן רח״ל בַּיי זַיין לֶעבִּין׃

In my own translation:

> It's written that someone who cries wholeheartedly when they read that the two sons of Aaron, the *kohen*, died is assured that his children will not die, God forbid, in his lifetime.

*Where's* it written?

Comment: Which machhzor?

Comment: @IsaacMoses I'd have to look up the title: I don't recall it. It was published by the Hebrew Publishing Co. in New York, some time in or before 1962. If I remember to, I'll _b'li neder_ edit the bibliographic info in to the question and delete these comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Mishnah Berurah 621:2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Berurah.621.2?lang=he) quotes this idea in the name of the Zohar. (I believe the relevant piece of Zohar is to be found in [Vol. III 57b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Zohar.3.57b.8?lang=he).)